# Rails: Sort most used acts_as_taggable tags by a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

I have set up two models: `user` and `post`. Each `post` `belongs_to` a `user`. `post`s also have tags, using acts_as_taggable. On `UserController#show` I want to list the tags the user uses, sorting from most used to less used.

Getting a list of tags is not hard, but how can I sort them? I use this to find the tags:

```
@tags = []
@user.posts.each do |post|
  @tags += post.tags
end
```

Can anyone explain me how I can sort the tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use tag_counts method provided by plugin:

```
@user.posts.tag_counts
```

more info here: http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

EDIT:

a basic simple code for sorting:

```
@tags = Hash.new(0)
@user.posts.each do |post|
  post.tags.each do |tag|
    @tags[tag] += 1 if @tags.has_key?(tag)
  end
end
# sorting
@tags.sort{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
```

maybe there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: This only counts the tags, not sorts them.

Comment: well, at the moment I haven't any code to make some test, btw it should return some structure (array or hash) with tags and their count. then you should only sort it ;)